# Producing my own Cumulative Flow Diagram with data from Jira for a Scrum project

Tags: report, reporting, project-management, scrum, jira-agile

My team uses a Jira Team Managed project and the CFD chart there is not useful because the time period is for the lifetime of the project rather than a period you want to look at.

This has left me with only the option to make my own by using a webhook when an issue is transitioned and putting it into Google Sheets.

The data I have is the task status *from* and *to* as well as the date it was done.

Using this data I've then created a row for each date as well as the tasks for each status, cumulative for the day. For example if on day 1 there are 3 tickets in progress and then on day 2 another ticket moves to in progress, day 2 would register 4 tickets.

The data looks like this:

[image]

and the chart ends up looking like this:

[image]

Am I approaching this correctly? I'm concerned specifically about:

1. The cumulative nature of the figures each day for every single ticket status.
2. The cart. The y-axis data number is useless because if the stacking of the charts but is this the correct chart type to be using?

Cheers.